# What makes cows stop being able to produce milk?

Tags: pathology, reproduction, speculative

I'm writing a paper about cows and want to discuss why they stop producing milk. Is there a disease that causes them to stop producing milk?

Comment: OP noted that they had difficulty logging in - namely that it still treated them as a guest even though they were logged in.